# Proving the convergence of a sequence by using epsilon

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to prove that the sequence $ \left \lfloor{ \frac{ 10 + n }{ 2n } }\right \rfloor $converges to 0 by using the episilon method.

I tend to work backwards. So far, I've managed to do the following:
\begin{align}
|\left \lfloor{ \frac{ 10 + n }{ 2n } }\right \rfloor - 0 | 
&= |\left \lfloor{ \frac{ 10 + n }{ 2n } }\right \rfloor | \\
&\leq |\left \lfloor{ \frac{ 10 + n }{ 2n } }\right \rfloor | \\
&\leq | \frac{ 10 + n }{ 2n } | \\
&= \frac{ 10 + n }{ 2n } \\
&\leq \frac{ 10 + n }{ n } \\
&= \frac{ 10 }{ n } + 1 \\
\end{align}

Then, I took $ \epsilon > \frac{ 10 }{ n } + 1 $, which lead to having $ n > \frac{ 10 }{ \epsilon - 1 } $. Thus, it is sufficient to take $ N > \frac{ 10 }{ \epsilon - 1 } $ to guarantee that for all $ n \geq N $,  $ |\left \lfloor{ \frac{ 10 + n }{ 2n } }\right \rfloor - 0 | < \epsilon $.

The problem I am having is that the previous must hold for all $ \epsilon > 0 $, including $ \epsilon = 1 $. It can be shown manually that for $ n \leq 11 $, $ |\left \lfloor{ \frac{ 10 + n }{ 2n } }\right \rfloor - 0 | < 1 $, so the way I defined $ N $ is not completely incorrect.

I am wondering if there is a way to define $ N $ so that I don't have to consider various cases.

Comment: This isn't an answer, so a comment: I would prove this by breaking it into two pieces. $(1)$ Show that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x\notin\Bbb Z$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lfloor x_n\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor$ (this rules out cases for sequences like $(-1)^n/n$). $(2)$ Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(10+n)/2n=1/2$ via the epsilon-delta method and apply the first part. I also tend to make things more difficult than necessary, so feel free to completely ignore my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, if $n>10$, then $\left\lfloor\frac{10+n}{2n}\right\rfloor=0.$ So for any $\epsilon>0$, if $n>10$, then 
$$\left|\left\lfloor\frac{10+n}{2n}\right\rfloor-0\right|=0<\epsilon.$$
In other words  $N_\epsilon=10$. This proves that the limit is $0$.

The reason your first method does not work is that your upper bounds are too loose. The floor function is critical for the limit being $0$, so you cannot just throw it away. Similarly, $2$ in the denominator should not be discarded.